# What species are the Minions?

Tags: despicable-me

In *Despicable Me*, Gru has an army of minions who do everything from looking after the girls to assist him in his attempts to become a super villain.

But what are they? Are they aliens? Are they modeled on some sort of creatures?

Comment: TWINKIES!  TWINKIES OF DOOM!

Comment: Kind of a silly question... They're fictional, what kind of answer could you possibly expect? Nonetheless, great answer by Ankit though.

Comment: @poepje Superman is fictional but we know what species he is!

Comment: @Liath Because that is mentioned perhaps, but in Despicable Me it isn't. Which should mean the writers never decided what race they are.

Comment: @poepje well that's kind of the question isn't it?  As Ankit said - they're not named.  That doesn't mean that it's a silly question, it just means that there isn't an answer (yet)!

Comment: Since no one really knows what the minions are or where they came from that raises the quotation of how long have they been around? Well, think of it this way, perhaps they had been genetically engineered by a villain in Atlantis to help him sink it.

Comment: Just a meta observation; it's a fair question. Sometimes issues like this come up and this site is perfect to help. The collected base of users may have a better eye on interviews, quote memory, additional media which might give sufficient data that the average person might not know or have missed. The site gives a fantastic place to correlate that data if it exists.

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/39659/4918 Where did the Minions come from? on Science Fiction and Fantasy SE

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It may be explored in [Minions (film)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minions_%28film%29)  which would act as a prequel or spin off to the *Despicable Me franchise* coming in 2014. The movie description in Wikipedia it states -

> Minions are yellow henchmen who have existed since the beginning of
>   time, serving history's most ambitious villains.

But for now they are just servants/followers etc etc. If they are alien, humanoid, or some different species any guess is still just speculation.

---

**Update:** As per then [Minions (film)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minions_%28film%29)

> Minions are small, yellow creatures who have existed since the
>   beginning of time, evolving from single-celled organisms into beings
>   who exist only to serve history's most despicable masters.